# Generated heading tags via jQuery - Now trying to insert HTML as per the previous UL children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have generated and inserted new `h2` elements with jQuery. I am trying to make the text of the `h2` elements match the text of the existing `li` elements.

Can anyone please help?

Here is the fiddle URL and code:

http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/uSxyN/17/

```
$('<h2/>').insertBefore('.nested-coll-cont');

var h1Index = $('.nested-coll-control > h2').index(), 
    headingHtml = $('.nested-coll-tabs > li').eq(h1Index).html()

$('.nested-coll-control > h2').text(headingHtml);
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: @Bryan..thanks for the editing and realizing me that the question had to corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set `h2` title text based on the list item text then you can do:

```
$('<h2/>').insertBefore('.nested-coll-cont');

$.each($('.nested-coll-control > h2'), function() {
    var h1Index = $(this).index('h2'), 
        headingHtml = $('.nested-coll-tabs > li').eq(h1Index).html();
    $(this).text(headingHtml);
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSxyN/19/)**

Comment: thanks for the quick turn around... exactly this what i am looking for.... there is only one thing can you please look at the fiddle URL now and tell me the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/mufeedahmad/uSxyN/24/

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uSxyN/18/)

No idea what you are doing, but may be this will help :-

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {    
    var headingHtml = $('.nested-coll-tabs > li').eq(i).html();
    $('.nested-coll-control > h2').eq(i).text(headingHtml);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help... but can't fix the children's limit "<=2"

Comment: you need to use `count` then